# SQL query to cross-reference the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, cross-reference

I have a below query where I'm using left-outer join to cross-reference the same table. Basically I would like to cross-reference Min_Size_Code field to reflect Min_Actual_size and Max_Size_Code field to reflect Max_Actual_Size. However, I'm not getting the correct answer I'm looking for.

Below is my answer based on the SQL query

[image]

Ideal answer should be as below

[image]

Below is my code

```
select A.week,A.style,A.Color, A.location, A.Actual_size, A.size_code, A.Min_size_code, A.Max_size_code,
min(B.Actual_size) over(partition by A.week,A.style,A.Color,A.location) Min_Actual_Size,
max(B.Actual_size) over(partition by A.week,A.style,A.Color,A.location) Max_Actual_Size

from
(
select week, style, Color, location, Actual_size, size_code,
min(size_code)over(partition by week,style,Color,location) min_size_code,
max(size_code)over(partition by week,style,Color,location) max_size_code

from TestSizeTable where Style = 'AB123' and color = 'WY4567'
and week = '202002'  and location in ( '111')
) A
Left outer Join 
TestSizeTable B
on ( A.Style = B.Style and A.Color = B.Color and A.Week = B.Week
and A.Location = B.Location)
where (B.size_code = A.min_size_code or B.size_code = A.max_size_code)
```

Any help would be great!!

Comment: I would split out the MIN/MAX referencing - If you want to reference the same table in two different ways consider using a CTE that has two queries - the first winkles out the MIN values and the second the MAX values. the main SQL statement then has two joins, one to each CTE subset. If you have a lot of data (millions of rows) the same may work quicker with temp tables if you can filter the rows down in them.

Comment: @pixelda, I tried to solve the issue by creating 2 different leftouter join. One for Min_Actual_Size and one for Max_Actual_Size and it worked. However, is there any easy way?

Comment: I suggest looking at each source of data and think of how you can write SQL that gives you a small set of data from that area. Use as few columns as possible. I put these sets of SQL into a CTE and bring them together with further SQL to join the smaller sets into bigger ones. Finally I link to any other data needed in the result. By this point I have the fewest rows to join which is always faster. The bottom line is to think in sets and joins between them rather than the procedural mechanism for getting the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the data type of the column actual_size. I suspect it's `varcahr` and in that case 14 is less than 2.

Your code works fine [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4917985ed0358ea3dadf4c13cf3a1577).

Please check the updated solution for the `varchar` column (actual_size) **[HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a78706f768d2ff523cde512521c088f)**.

Comment: I tried converting Actual_Size column to int. However, it fails when there to choose smaller size between 00 and 0. Because the underneath ASCII character of 00 and 0 is same (when converted to int) and the system always pick 0 as minimum while we want 00 as smallest compare to 0.

Comment: @DhruvBhatt that's the new twist of information you provided now. are there any other variants of 0 e.g. 000 etc.? even in varchar, '0' is less than '00'.

Comment: Sorry to provide you the latest information in 0 size variation. Even I just found out recently. We don't have 000 in size. The only thing is to pick 00 size as smaller than 0.

Comment: @DhruvBhatt please check the latest solution update in the answer.

Comment: @sacese this is fantastic!! Thank you so much for helping me over it!!

Comment: @DhruvBhatt gr8, Thanks! I never used a trigonometric function before in SQL server to sort the values. Thanks for putting such unique questions.

Comment: Yes, I saw you're using cos function which something very different and new. Thanks for your time and help us getting learn something new.

Comment: @DhruvBhatt that's the only way I could figure out to make 00 smaller than 0 :). COS gives larger values with smaller inputs (so after replacing values, COS(1) gives higher value than COS(11)).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ideal way however I got an answer from below modified code.

```
Select A.week,A.style,A.Color, A.location, A.Actual_size, A.size_code, A.Min_size_code, A.Max_size_code,
Min_Actual_Size,Max_Actual_Size
from
(
select A.week,A.style,A.Color, A.location, A.Actual_size, A.size_code, A.Min_size_code, A.Max_size_code,
max(B.Actual_size) over(partition by A.week,A.style,A.Color,A.location) Max_Actual_Size,
(
select A.week,A.style,A.Color, A.location, A.Actual_size, A.size_code, A.Min_size_code, A.Max_size_code,
min(B.Actual_size) over(partition by A.week,A.style,A.Color,A.location) Min_Actual_Size,
from
(
select week, style, Color, location, Actual_size, size_code,
min(size_code)over(partition by week,style,Color,location) min_size_code,
max(size_code)over(partition by week,style,Color,location) max_size_code
from TestSizeTable where Style = 'AB123' and color = 'WY4567'
and week = '202002'  and location in ( '111')
) A
Left outer Join 
TestSizeTable B
on ( A.Style = B.Style and A.Color = B.Color and A.Week = B.Week
and A.Location = B.Location)
where B.size_code = A.min_size_code
) A
Left outer Join 
TestSizeTable B
on ( A.Style = B.Style and A.Color = B.Color and A.Week = B.Week
and A.Location = B.Location)
where B.size_code = A.max_size_code
) A
```